# Java For Loop repeat if value is more

Tags: java, string, char

I am taking characters from a string and its values are added still I am getting  a particular value.. suppose my value to get is 50 .. i need to take character each from a string and add its values

for example the value I need to get is 10

and value for letters a=1,b=2,c-3;

and the string is abca so its total value is 1+2+3+1 = 7

so 10 didn't reached so I need to add once agin from start like abca 7 + 1 + 2. So at the place of b we got the 10 value.. so the result is 2.

I know how to take the value for once but the second time calculation an dthird time I am not getting if anyone can help..pls help

The code so far I completed..

```
long currentValueFN = 0;
long value = 0;
char[] currentFN = new char[text.length()];
currentFN = text.toCharArray(); 
Long l = Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(currentAge));                      
for(int i=0; i<text.length(); i++)
{
   currentValueFN += valueLetters( currentFN[i] );                     
   if(currentValueFN >= l)
   {
      value = valueLetters( currentFN[i] );
   }
} 
return value;
```

Comment: I right understand that, your get part of characters and trying to add it until you get required value, and if its not enough you get more? OR you get all characters from text and it may be not enough and you want to start from the first character of the text?

Comment: both option or first or second?

Comment: This is for a numerology app where , users first name is taking... and for each letter there is corresponding values are there and it is adding...and all that values are added so.. for example my name is 'ab' so let we take value for a=1 and b=2. so total value is 3 .. only but the value we need to reach is 5 ..in that case we need to add once again

Comment: from 'a' to the reult so our value now is 2+1 = 3 then once again we will start from a so 3+1 =4 ..so we don't reach 5 we take value of 'b' it is 2 4+2 = 6 that means 5 over

Comment: so we can take b as our required result value ...but we dont need b its value we needed for calculation so we take b's value it is 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
long currentValueFN = 0;
long value = 0;
char[] currentFN = new char[text.length()];
currentFN = text.toCharArray();
Long l = Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(currentAge));  
while(currentValueFN < l ) //check if current value is enough
{

  for(int i=0; i<text.length(); i++) 
  {
     currentValueFN += valueLetters( currentFN[i] );                     
     if(currentValueFN >= l)
     {
        value = valueLetters( currentFN[i] );
        break;
     }
  }
} 
return value;
```

1) if there are enough characters in "text": will escape from `for` by `break` and then from `while` by expression;

2) if there aren't enough characters in "text": will finish `for` and start it again by `while` expression. until 1)

Comment: Thanks z Cuzz...I think this will work..let me check

Comment: Yes it is working,,.. Thankz Cuzz... I am accepting your answer...Thankz once again

Answer (score 1):

please forgive me if my answer is wrong.
1)I have taken a string variable called "variable" and converted it to character array called "character_array"(array name).

2)Then i converted the character array elements to its equivalent ascii code and it is stored in an integer array called "value_array"(array name).

3)Then i checked the condition that the givenvalue is less than the addedvalue.

public class Stack {

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    long addedvalue=0;
    long requiredvalue=600;
    String variable="ravi";
    char characterarray[]=new char[variable.length()];
    for(int i=0;i<variable.length();i++)
    {
        characterarray[i]=variable.charAt(i);
        System.out.println(characterarray[i]);
    }
    int valuearray[]=new int[variable.length()];
    for(int j=0;j<variable.length();j++)
    {
        valuearray[j]=(int)(variable.charAt(j));
        System.out.println(valuearray[j]);
    }

    while(addedvalue<=requiredvalue)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<variable.length();j++)
        {
            valuearray[j]=(int)(variable.charAt(j));
            if(addedvalue>=requiredvalue)
                break;
            addedvalue=addedvalue+valuearray[j];
            System.out.println(j);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

This should help you.

```
currentValueFN =0;
a=0;
while(currentValueFN !=l){
    a=valueLetters( currentFN[i] ); 
    currentValueFN +=a;
    if(currentValueFN >= l)
    {
         value = a;
         break;
    }
}

return value;
```